# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, API TMDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am using the TMDB API which allows me to display movies in a list.

I have my Add.js component which allows me to make a query and search for the movies and add them to my list

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

**Add.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ResultCard } from "./ResultCard";

export const Add = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setQuery(e.target.value);

    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false&query=${e.target.value}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data.errors) {
          setResults(data.results);
        } else {
          setResults([]);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="add-page">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="add-content">
          <div className="input-wrapper">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search for a movie"
              value={query}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </div>

          {results.length > 0 && (
            <ul className="results">
              {results.map((movie) => (
                <li key={movie.id}>
                  <ResultCard movie={movie} />
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi There ! Can you create a codesandbox project and share the link. Also include your ResultCard Component as well :)

Comment: So it means your `results` are undefined from `useState`? Make sure it's pre-defined to empty array

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mcnulty-shwxv?file=/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening at this line of code:

```
.then((data) => {
    if (!data.errors) { // This is always giving error false since errors property is not returned from API
      setResults(data.results);
    } else {
      setResults([]);
    }
 });
```

The returned response data is:

> {status_code: 7, status_message: "Invalid API key: You must be granted
> a valid key.", success: false} status_code: 7 status_message: "Invalid
> API key: You must be granted a valid key." success: false

The reason for this is because the `data` that is returned from the API has no `errors` property.

You need to use `data.success` property instead of `data.errors`.

**THE CODESANDBOX WORKING CODE:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-1ng77?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it works, thanks to you! But I don't get the movies from the API :(
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mcnulty-shwxv?file=/

Comment: Welcome Mate :) Ok, So for that we need to see how to implement their API. Check once from their website. And see if you are implementing the API as mentioned in the Docs. :) Let me know if it still doesn't work. Do give it a one more try first !!! :-D

Comment: with a console.log I retrieve the data from my API but it is not displayed this must come from my ResulCard.js component

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `results` is undefined.

Try to console log the result after fetching data, maybe you set your data to undefined or something.

To quickly fix that, you can do something like

```
{results?.length > 0 && ( ... )}
```